# Orientation changes destroys ftp uploading in android activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, ftp, orientation

I am creating an android app which has an option to take picture using phone's camera and upload to ftp server. But sometimes camera open in landscape and it turns my activity into landscape and destroys the process of uploading to server. How do i overcome this issue?

Note: i have added orientation="potrait" and onconfigchanes="keyboardhidden|orientation" inside manifest of my activity

Comment: I do not know how you were able to run IO in the main thread. You should use a  AsyncTask or a background service to do the uploading.

Comment: Ofcourse im doing uploading in async task..but getting the original image and saving it into a file from camera is done on main. I guess that is destroyed on config changes. Btw how do i use onconfigchanes??

Comment: Did you try to add Santiago solution

Comment: Yes that works for now but how do i use onConfigChanges? Because in othef casr i connect to a remote ftp via ip address and port number but when the screen rotates it disconnects the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your activity that upload to ftp in the manifest

Comment: This is the correct answer, But his approach is incorrect. :)

Comment: Yes, is better use onConfigurationChanged but he can test with this for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should make the ftp upload into an async task. That way it can execute regardless of what the activity does from that point. Then if need be, have the activity respond to when the async task has completed.